# shapley graph plot via python

Tags: shap

Does anybody know how can we plot this graph? Sth like attached.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at the SHAP package. Here is a link to some [similar examples](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/tabular_examples/tree_based_models/Scatter%20Density%20vs.%20Violin%20Plot%20Comparison.html).

As described in these examples, the following code will produce the both plots:

```
import xgboost
import shap

# train xgboost model on diabetes data:
X, y = shap.datasets.diabetes()
bst = xgboost.train({"learning_rate": 0.01}, xgboost.DMatrix(X, label=y), 100)

# explain the model's prediction using SHAP values on the first 1000 training data samples
shap_values = shap.TreeExplainer(bst).shap_values(X)

# plot the global importance of each feature
shap.plots.bar(shap_values)

# plot the distribution of importances for each feature over all samples
shap.plots.summary(shap_values)
```